# Get CPU RAM HDD load from Windows registry

Tags: windows, registry, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012

I Is it possible to get this values from windows registry:

- Total CPU load and for each core
- RAM utilization
- HDD Utilization
- Network upload and download speed
- Number of services on the system.

  I suppose that this information is stored somewhere in Windows registry.

Comment: no, that information is not stored in the registry

Comment: No, this kind of information is not in the registry. What about WMI or performance counters ?

Comment: Can I access WMI or performance counters with pure Java code?